# Beamer/TikZ: Uncover nodes in segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to uncover the text nodes of a tikzpicture. This is the desired result:

**Slide 1**

[image]

**Slide 2**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (-3,-2) -- node[below] {a} (3,-2) -- node[right] {b} (2,3) -- node[above] {c} (-2,2) -- node[left] {d} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**What I tried so far...**

1

```
\uncover<2->{node[below] {a}}
```

2

```
{\uncover<2->{node[below] {a}}}
```

3

```
node[below] \uncover<2->{{a}}
```

4

```
node[below] {\uncover<2->{{a}}}
```

5

```
node[below] {\uncover<2->{a}}
```

6

```
node[below] {{\uncover<2->{a}}}
```

...but I got always errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to use `\uncover` on separate `\draw` commands like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \uncover<1>{\draw[ultra thick](-3,-2)--(3,-2)--(2,3)--(-2,2)--cycle;}
  \uncover<2->{\draw[ultra thick](-3,-2)--node[below]{a}(3,-2)--node[right]{b}(2,3)--node[above]{c}(-2,2)--node[left]{d} cycle;}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]